# Mix doesn't render browser window - "unable to resolve the server's DNS address"

Tags: browsers, mix, dns

I am trying to do the [Mix getRating tutorial](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Mix:-The-DApp-IDE) from GitHub.  After I enter the solidity code and the html code, the Mix status bar indicates that it compiled successfully. However, the browser windows show an error icon with the message "Unable to resolve the server's DNS address."  The status bar of the browser window shows:  http://localhost:50939/index.html.

When I click on refresh, the Mix status bar gives the following error message:
WebContainer.html - line 46 - Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a fram with origin "http://locahost:50939" from accessing a frame with origin "null". The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "data". Protocols must match.

I am running Mix 1.0.1 and Mac El Capitan.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a firewall running?

Comment: No firewall running.